# Serializing textarea with wrap="hard" doesn't give line breaks

Tags: jquery, serialization, textarea, word-wrap

I have a textarea with "hard" wrapping:

```
<textarea name="text" cols=5 wrap="hard">a b c d e f</textarea>
```

When I serialize this textarea with jquery I get:

```
text="a+b+c+d+e+f"
```

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/gTWhC/) The problem is that I want to get the line breaks from the textarea.

If I actually submit the form, then on the server I see the form come in with the proper line breaks. But I'd like to be able to get the line breaks without having to reload the page. I've already tried using the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) with no luck. And I've tried having my form [target an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568876/html-get-wrapped-text-from-textarea), but that comes with its own problems.

**Is it possible to get the line breaks from a textarea without reloading the page?**

Comment: Very good question, I would really like to know this as well! Please tell me if you found a solution :)

Comment: I've een trying to do this all day. Seems odd that it changes the format when there is a browser refresh. If anyone can shed any light on this it would be helpful.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is a bug in jquery? I'm running into the same issue right now.