# jQuery post textarea wrap hard not show line break

Tags: jquery

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $.post('/0002.php', $('#foo').serialize(),      
    function(output){
        $('#output').html(output);
    }); 
});

<form name="foo" id="foo">
    <textarea name="t" wrap="hard"></textarea>
    <span id="submit">Click</span>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

//PHP

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['t'])){
    echo nl2br($_POST['t']);
}
?>
```

I have a textarea set wrap hard, but its not working when I use jQuery post, jQuery post doesn't show the line breaks.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: according to the documentation nl2br will insert <br/> before \r\n, \n\r, \n and \r http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php
Have you checked that textarea is actually producing those?

Comment: i tried normal post without jquery and it works

Comment: watch carefully, im click span not submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is because the 't' is going to be passed at PHP only if you submit normally your form. Since you are doing it by ajax you have to pass this as parameter to your post request in jquery, something that is not the case. In your case You are using serialize for the whole form that probably removes the new lines from the textarea..Open your chromebug/firebug and check what exactly are you sending as a data load for the POST request and give an update so we can help.

So the only solution workarounds would be:

- Either parse the textarea and with the given width calculate how many chars can fit and put a 
  or \r\n after that in a hidden input/div and send it. Char width is difficult to find though and the font should be fixed width.
- Or do an actual POST but have do it to an iframe as it was discussed in the link I sent (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2142815/986160).

Comment: i found this post has same problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574365/serializing-textarea-with-wrap-hard-doesnt-give-line-breaks

Comment: In the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gTWhC/ I removed the wrap="hard" and I don't see any difference. From 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_wrap.asp
I read that wrap="hard" wraps the textarea text with new lines as the form is submitted. Neither this example nor the one you sent submits the form - you do an ajax call on click. In order to submit the form you have to do $("form_id").submit() or something similar. In other words you don't submit the form so the wrap="hard" is simply ignored.. I don't see a problem here..

Comment: Check this discussion and some proposed solutions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140573/html-textarea-use-javascript-to-get-wrapped-text

Comment: I was playing around (http://jsfiddle.net/gTWhC/14/) and it seems that the new lines that are implicit (because of wrap) are ignored since they are not sent to the server and the explicit ones (if you hit enter) can be seen. Two approaches if the formatting is so important to you - btw out of curiosity  can you tell us the reason why is that important to you? Either parse the textarea and with the given width calculate how many chars can fit and put a <br/>or \r\n after that in a hidden input/div and send it. Or do an actual POST but have it in an iframe is it was discussed in the link I sent.

Comment: because I need to use this text create in php GD, thas why i need line break